# Good Way to Create a Cross-Platform Library for an Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I'm developing an app for both Android and iOS, and I'm considering writing the UI with each platform's native tools (the alternative in this case would be to use Flex). However, I would like to at least contain the core functionality in a cross-platform library so I don't have to rewrite it for each OS.

The library will need to process strings / characters in languages other than English, so I'll need Unicode support or something similar, but that's about it, because it won't be doing anything really complicated.

Is there a good way to do this?

Thank you very much.

P.S. I'm also curious how most large projects do this. What is the most accepted way to do this; do they completely rewrite the app for each platform, or what are the most popular solutions?

Comment: If you want one code base C++ will be a solution here. You can later build a library (frameworks) for each of platforms. Check projects like Cocos2dx for example.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Does it make sense to use Cocos2dx for an app that's not a game? Are there any alternatives for non-game apps? Thx

Comment: I'm surprised this question has seen so little activity. True cross-platform libraries seem like an important thing. I understand the difficulties relating to UI and other system specific things. But, I'm talking about platform general code.